# Duplicate unique constraint in PostgreSQL database table

Tags: postgresql

I accidentally (during a database migration) created a unique constraint on the columns, that already had the same unique constraint defined. Basically I ended up with this:

```
=> select * from information_schema.table_constraints where table_name = 'users' and constraint_type = 'UNIQUE';
 constraint_catalog | constraint_schema | constraint_name  | table_catalog | table_schema | table_name | constraint_type | is_deferrable | initially_deferred
--------------------+-------------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------
 fo-auth            | public            | users_email_key  | fo-auth       | public       | users      | UNIQUE          | NO            | NO
 fo-auth            | public            | users_email_key1 | fo-auth       | public       | users      | UNIQUE          | NO            | NO
(2 rows)
```

Is this something to worry about, or can I live with it?

Answer (score 1):

Just drop the redundant constraint:

```
alter table users drop constraint users_email_key1;
```

Two same constraints don't do any harm, but unnecessarily make inserts and updates longer.